# retrofit 2 - how to pass a POST json object

Tags: android, gson

So, i have a List of my custom Object and I need a JSON like this:

```
{
"surveys": [{
    "survey": {
        "code": "05052017153632",
        "date": "05/05/2017 15:36:32",
        "device_id": 1,
        "questions_attributes": [{
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "Você encontrou tudo o que procurava?",
            "value": "Infelizmente, não"
        }, {
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "Em qual departamento você não encontrou o produto?",
            "value": "FERRAMENTAS, TAPETES"
        }, {
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "Deseja que a Havan entre em contato com você?",
            "value": "Não informado"
        }, {
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "Nome",
            "value": "Não informado"
        }, {
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "E-mail",
            "value": "Não informado"
        }, {
            "kind": "string",
            "label": "Telefone",
            "value": "Não informado"
        }]
    }
}]}
```

But I dont have any ideia how to do it using Gson.
I'm Using Retrofit 2 and need to pass this JSON into a body request.
Any ideias?

Comment: See [Retrofit 2 — Constant, Default and Logic Values for POST and PUT Requests](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-constant-default-and-logic-values-for-post-and-put-requests) tutorial

Comment: @FarshidABZ I need help to parse tojson on this format, I know how to pass to WS

Comment: The problem is the Gson.toJson is freezing my UI

Comment: Do that on a worker thread so the ui can keep running

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw this question that I made 1 year ago and I`m using another solution nowdays. If someone still needs a help and looking for this, here we go:

I have made a function to handle the JSON format that I want:

```
 public String serialize(List<Object> objects, String arrKey, String 
     objKey) {
    JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
    for (Object object: objects) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(object);
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.add(objKey, je);
        ja.add(jo);
    }

    JsonObject objMain = new JsonObject();
    objMain.add(arrKey,ja);

    return objMain.toString();

}
```

And in my API Call I have this line:

```
     String json = new CustomGsonAdapter().serialize(surveysList, "surveys","survey");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
```

`RequestBody` is the trick. Now, just need to pass this `RequestBody` to retrofit call and thats it.

```
@POST("surveys")
Call<Void> setSurveys(@Body RequestBody json);
```

I dont know if this is the best way to archieve the problem, but for me it was.
Save time and avoid to create a class just to send to server.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you need to pass this JSON into body request.

### Retrofit Interface:

```
public interface RetrofitInterface<R extends RetrofitClass> {
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"})
    @POST("v1/auth/")

 public Call<ResponseBody> callLogin(@Query("key") String key, @Body LoginModel body);
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"})

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConstants.mBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

### Api call Activity:

pass json object into body request use @Body param.

Here you can create gson model classes in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ 
json to gson converter by using that json request format.

After that set values with that gson pojo classes and pass the json object to body request in retrofit.

### For example:

### LoginModel:

```
public class LoginModel {
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

### set Values with pojo class:

```
LoginModel model_obj = new LoginModel();
    mModel_obj.setUsername(mUsername);
    mModel_obj.setPassword(mPassword);
```

### Api calling:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.callLogin(AppConstants.mApiKey, model_obj);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

above code will be written in Api Service Interface.
and then you can call this from RestClient class(by Retrofit instance) by passing a JsonObject as Body.