# How to post request { "nargout":1, "rhs":[1] } with retrofit in kotlin?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, rest

I have request json:

```
{
    "nargout":1, 
    "rhs":[1]
}
```

and the response:

```
{
    "lhs": [
        {
            "mwdata": [
                1
            ],
            "mwsize": [
                1,
                1
            ],
            "mwtype": "double"
        }
    ]
}
```

how set that into android studio with retrofit in kotlin?
i just want to take mwdata as response

this is Content-Type: application/json by the way....

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrofit 2 - how to pass a POST json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853436/retrofit-2-how-to-pass-a-post-json-object)

Comment: but i want to do it with kotlin

Comment: Use the android studio to convert this java code to kotlin.